# How to translate「じっくり見たことなかったですよね」?

Tags: translation

I'm trying to translate a little snippet to practice my Japanese. However the sentence「じっくり見たことなかったですよね」is giving me some trouble.

A friend of mine said that it would be more literal to translate it as "I've never studied you before", though it doesn't exactly make sense in the context...
I think *"I've never seen you like this before"* would make more sense in the context? I'm not exactly sure how to translate it.

Here's the whole panel:

> か: なんだ？
>
> て: 眼鏡ないと印象変わるよな〜
>
> **つ: じっくり見たことなかったですよねー**
>
> か: ジロジロ見るんじゃない！

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

「じっくり」 would mean "carefully" in this context.  (The more words in the  「〇っ〇り」 pattern you learn, the more natural your Japanese will become.  The second character is the small っ and not the regular-size つ.)

か: What is it?

て: He looks totally different without his glasses on, doesn't he?

つ: I'd never looked at him so carefully before.

か: Stop staring at me like that!